# PhpStorm autocomplete STD Object not working

Tags: php, json, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm to build my next project. ATM I'm looking for a clean way to save all my post requests, instead of checking them all one by one using `isset` etc.. so I can loop my `stdObject`.

I'm trying to make a STD Object, but PHP is not autocompleting it. I think I should be using PHPDoc but can't get any to work.

**So how do I get PhpStorm to autocomplete the STD Object**

I hope someone knows how!

*PS: If you think of a better way to save the `$_POST` value's let me know!*

Code:

```
$errors = 0;

$mandatory = [
    'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
    'last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
    ];

$mandatory = json_decode(json_encode($mandatory));

$mandatory->
```

[image: Phpstorm Screenshot]

Comment: are you asking how to validate the incoming data? It's not really clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @ADyson Updated the post, put the "main question" in bold.

Comment: Right so it's a question about the IDE. But why don't you just declare an object / class to begin with instead of an array? I would guess it doesn't autocomplete because it's not based on some other hard-coded compilable code. instead you're creating an object by _executing_ some code instead of writing it - a compiler won't be able to know the outcome of the execution (even if in this case it's predictable).

Comment: Because i wanna loop truth the array, so i dont have to if(isset) every thing time, So i can just do foreach($mandatory as $key => $value){ if(isset($value)){return true}}

Comment: In that case why do you need an object at all? BTW there are probably existing validation solutions available for PHP if you google. I very much doubt you need to re-invent the wheel on this topic.

Comment: Because, i can use $mandatory->first_name instead of $mandatory['first_name'], i was hoping there was a way that the -> would autocomplete.

Comment: there's no way to make stdClass autocomplete in phpstorm

Comment: Not unless you declare it as a concrete class to begin with. BTW you can perfectly easily loop over the properties of a class, so there isn't really any need to start off with an array. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Comment: Declare a simple class with real fields like Álvaro González is proposing or with PHPDoc fields (using `@property` tag). Still needs a class defined (but I would recommend this way -- better scalability in the future). Otherwise -- use plain array with **deep-assoc-completion plugin**.

Answer (score 2):

Objects of type `stdClass` do not have standard properties, only custom ones. So PhpStorm does not have any obvious way to figure out what to suggest. Even a human will have troubles since your code feeds from external input thus can contain anything.

Hacking with stubs can be a way but it'll affect the entire codebase.

A possible solution is to declare a custom object anywhere in your project (the code is there to be parsed by PhpStorm, it does not even need to be executed at all):

```
class MandatoryPost extends stdClass
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $first_name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $last_name;
}
```

… and provide some hints here and there:

```
/** @var MandatoryPost $mandatory */
$mandatory->
```

However, it feels like complete overkill. The only reason why you have `stdClass` in the first place is because you perform a dubious JSON serialization on what's otherwise fairly procedural code. If you want to validate using objects then create a proper class that takes care of the whole thing:

```
$user = User::createFromPost($_POST);
if ($user->isComplete()) {
}
```

... or just work with plain arrays all the time.

Comment: Not sure why's he supposed to extend from the `\stdClass`. This should be a POPO.

Comment: @emix To make the object as close as possible as the actual type. But I don't have PhpStorm here to verify, perhaps it doesn't display any useful information from that.

Comment: BTW, you made me google for POPO and my PC is configured for Spanish... xD

Comment: LOL you made my day.

Answer (score 1):

> i'm looking for a clean way
>
> I'm trying to make a STD Object

Those sentences are mutually exclusive. If you want to make it clean way then create your own class for that data and populate it ex. using hydrator.

I don't know exactly where you want to save it but you have plenty of options. For example you can serialise an object.

If you want to it with "array way" then you can use this simple function

```
function checkMandatory(array $mandatoryFields, array $array) {
     return !array_diff_key(array_flip(mandatoryFields), $array);
}
```

usage

```
var_dump(checkMandatory(['first_name', 'last_name'], $_POST));
```

Comment: Thanks! I love the idea. But i also wanna be able to use the variables later on. So thats why i wanna declare a array, so can i even use this:     $mandatory->first_name = stripslashes($mandatory->first_name);
    $mandatory->last_name = stripslashes($mandatory->last_name);
    $mandatory->first_name = htmlspecialchars($mandatory->first_name);
    $mandatory->last_name = htmlspecialchars($mandatory->last_name); This works! But it is not auto completing..

Comment: then don't use stdClass but create an class and populate it from vars comming from $_POST

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class

```
<?php

class formFields
{
  private $first_name;
  private $last_name;

  public function __construct($first_name, $last_name)
  {
    $this->first_name = $first_name;
    $this->last_name = $last_name;
  }

  /**
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function getFirstName()
  {
    return $this->first_name;
  }

  /**
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function getLastName()
  {
    return $this->last_name;
  }

  /**
   * @param mixed $first_name
   */
  public function setFirstName($first_name)
  {
    $this->first_name = $first_name;
  }

  /**
   * @param mixed $last_name
   */
  public function setLastName($last_name)
  {
    $this->last_name = $last_name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yhea great idea man! But why use setters? You can just do $formFields::last_name right?

Comment: Its much cleaner to use getters and setters

Comment: Not trying to amend a perfectly fine answer, but setters/getters are often recommended as a way to provide further encapsulation. Since external code does not have direct access to public properties it's trivial to change the internal implementation, add validations, etc. In practice, 99% of the times they end up being nothing but empty boilerplate ;-)